# Adding multiple fields based on selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a simple dropdown where the user can select multiple options and based on the selected options, a corresponding input field will open up. I am using the Chosen jQuery plugin to accomplish this, and used the following JavaScript function to populate the input fields based on selected dropdown values, however it seems to open up only the latest selected value's input field.

To debug this I had created an empty array called `selected` and appended the chosen dropdown value to it, and then checked if the chosen values were in this array but it still seems to work the same way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected = [];
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            selected.push(optionValue);
            if(selected.includes(optionValue)){
                $(".field").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".field").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```